# node js backend security header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security

**im trying to make a login endpoint/api, and i am sending the user login data through the authentication headers, is that okay for the security?
the authorization headers is actually contains an object, it is encoded to a Base64, it contains user data like hashed password (not hashed yet in this code), username, and some sort of a serverkey (to authorize if it is the right client that sending an api request), just wanna make sure if it is secure or not..**

```js
const aFunction = (req, res) => {
        require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
            const token = buffer.toString('hex');
            const auth = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(req.headers.authorization, 'base64').toString('ascii')) 
        
            if(auth.serverkey == version["serverkey"]){
                loginUser(auth.username,token).then(data =>{
                
                    if (data.rows.length < 1 || data.rows[0].password != auth.password) {
                        res.send({
                            status: "failed", 
                            message: "Username/Password is wrong", 
                            status_code: 400
                        })
                    }else{
                        res.send({
                            status: "success", 
                            message: "successfully logged in", 
                            status_code: 200, token: token
                        })

                    }

                })
            }else{
                res.send({
                    status: "failed", 
                    message: "Unauthorized Client", 
                    status_code: 401
                })
            }
        });
        
            

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a check for `if (req.secure)` to your code, and reject any non-https request coming your way. (Don't do this if your nodejs program is behind a reverse proxy.)

Users with browsers can see *everything* you send back and forth to your server, whether via https or http. (devtools) So, if by reading your headers they can figure out how to send you malicious headers, then somebody will. And base64 encoding has exactly the same security as no encoding at all.  So salt and hash your passwords. Use the [bcrypt package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or jwts.

I would handle errors this way, by calling `next()` with an error parameter rather than by using `.send()` to deliver a failure message. Use this sort of code.

```js
const createError = require('http-errors')
 ...
const myfunction (req, res, next) {
  ...
  if (!req.secure) return next(createError(403, 'https required'))
  ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, ill try to implement it on my project